# how to get object that arepresent in object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, object

Actually I'm trying to get all the value of object1 and get true if Like object has some id that match with current user id

```
    Array [
  Object {
    "id": "-MgFbI5wXjtjKln1Wkqe",
    "like": Object {
      "-MgpHytKWNplejaxtLLF": "-MgpHytKWNplejaxtLLF",
    },
    "likes_count": 7,
  },
  Object {
    "id": "-MgpHytKWNplejaxtLLF",
    "like": Object {
      "-MgFbI5wXjtjKln1Wkqe": "aC9dL88GCAXdnGyefY1XDiXd7Iu1",
    },
    "likes_count": 0,
  },
]
```

Here is my code, `arr` contains whole object that are given above

```
   const us = arr.map((item) => {
        return item.like;
      });
      const ik = us.includes(uid);
      console.log("snap ", ik);
```

**I want given below object that include like variable true if like object have user id otherwise it assign false**

```
    Array [
Object {
    "id": "-MgFbI5wXjtjKln1Wkqe",
    "like":false,
    "likes_count": 7,
  },
  Object {
    "id": "-MgpHytKWNplejaxtLLF",
    "like":true,
    "likes_count": 0,
  },
]
```

Comment: can you attempt to clarify what you are trying to accomplish, what is happening, and what you want to happen?

Comment: You may be interested in [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Comment: Hi thanks for comments let me edit my post so that it will look more clear

Comment: Tip:  Trim out most of the extraneous properties and just use one or two representative example properties.  They are cluttering up the question.  You can also make use of the Snippet Tool to make this actual runnable code right here.  I suggest using the triple-backtick syntax for markdown of code that isn't runnable.  See [Markdown Editing Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: Thanks for comment i removed extra things

Comment: What does this have to do with react-native?

Answer (score 0):

```
const us =Array(); // us is the final table that you need 
for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
  us[i]= {
          "id":arr[i].id,
          "like": arr[i].like===uid?true:false,
          "likes_count": arr[i].likes_count,
         }
}
```

or this :

```
const us = Array();// us is the final table that you need
arr.forEach((element,index) => us[index] = {
  "id":arr[index].id,
  "like": arr[index].like===uid?true:false,
  "likes_count": arr[index].likes_count,} );
```

Comment: What is `usi`?   I think you have a typo.

Comment: sorry, i mean **uid** .